# Using if clause in knockout sortable example

Tags: knockout.js

The following code is working fine..

```
<div class="student" data-bind="text: gender()+'-'+name()"></div>
```

But, when I do the following, the if clause is not taken into account and all items have [M]appended to them..

```
<!-- ko if: gender()=="male" -->
            <div class="student" data-bind="text: '[M]'+name()"></div>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/768/)

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why the IF statement is not working directly but you can visually achieve the same thing by removing the IF statement and putting a visible on the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/770/

```
<div class="student" data-bind="visible:gender() =='male', text: '[M]'+name()"></div>
```

Shot in the dark but I assume you will want females as well... this will be a better way to achieve it..

http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/772/

```
<div class="student" data-bind="text: (gender() == 'male' ? '[M]':'[F]') + name()"></div>
```

Comment: the next one is definitely the one to use as visible:gender() =='male' makes the elements get copied instead of dragged when moved..

Answer (score 5):

I imagine this information from the [docs](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) is relevant

> Note: The sortable binding assumes that the child "templates" have a single container element. You cannot use containerless bindings (comment-based) bindings at the top-level of your template, as the jQuery draggable/sortable functionality needs an element to operate on.

I suspect this will achieve the same as you intended

```
<div class="seats" data-bind="sortable: { data: students, allowDrop: $root.isTableFull }">            
    <div class="student" data-bind="visible: gender() == 'male', text: '[M]'+name()"></div>
    <div class="student" data-bind="visible: gender() == 'female', text: '[F]'+name()"></div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/771/

Comment: thanks for the explanation but using visible: gender() == 'male' makes the application not work as before.. if I use it, then the elements in it after being dragged back to available students do not get moved but copied.. any idea why it happens?